# How to get list of tables used in a SQL Server 2005/2008 function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to get all related tables used in a **function**.

How to get list of tables used in a function in SQL Server 2005/2008?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.routines ISR
WHERE CHARINDEX('dbo.FunctionName', ISR.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, is there a way that I can use this kind of query? ;WITH stored_procedures AS (
SELECT 
o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row
FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
WHERE o.xtype = 'P')
SELECT proc_name, table_name FROM stored_procedures
WHERE row = 1
ORDER BY proc_name,table_name     with this query I got all the store procedure with related tables.